# Logstash grok filter does not parse message

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

In grok Debugger is everything okay but not parse when i start logstash.

Log line:

```
# Time: 170904 10:16:01\n# User@Host: mmcite[mmcite] @ localhost []\n# Thread_id: 18712  Schema: mmcite  QC_hit: No\n# Query_time: 0.502068  Lock_time: 0.000030  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1\n# Rows_affected: 1\nuse mmcite;\nSET timestamp=1504512961;\nUPDATE `ajedem456456` SET `id`='cotjo4mim2j7fp3ui2kit7gns6' WHERE id='pvueh0rm6l2meiguootdfqsan7';
```

Filter:

```
grok {

    match => { "message" => "#%{SPACE}Time:%{SPACE}%{NUMBER}%{SPACE}%{TIME}(.|\n)*%{HOSTNAME}\[%{HOSTNAME:mysql_host}\]%{SPACE}@%{SPACE}localhost \[\](.|\n)*#%{SPACE}Thread_id:%{SPACE}%{NUMBER}%{SPACE}Schema:%{SPACE}%{WORD}%{SPACE}%{WORD}:%{SPACE}%{WORD}(.|\n)*#%{SPACE}Query_time:%{SPACE}%{BASE16FLOAT:mysql_query_time}%{SPACE}Lock_time:%{SPACE}%{BASE16FLOAT:mysql_lock_time}%{SPACE}Rows_sent:%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:mysql_rows_sent}%{SPACE}Rows_examined:%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:mysql_rows_examined}(.|\n)*%{SPACE}Rows_affected:%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:mysql_rows_affected}(.|\n)*%{WORD}%{SPACE}%{WORD};(.|\n)*SET%{SPACE}timestamp=%{NUMBER:timestamp};\\n%{GREEDYDATA:mysql_query}" }

}
```

Output:

```
{
    "@timestamp" => 2017-09-04T13:08:06.260Z,
        "offset" => 3441,
      "@version" => "1",
    "input_type" => "log",
          "beat" => {
        "hostname" => "server.jerewan.cz",
            "name" => "server.jerewan.cz",
         "version" => "5.1.1"
    },
          "host" => "server.jerewan.cz",
        "source" => "/usr/home/admin/filebeat/mysql.slow.log",
       "message" => "# Time: 170904 10:16:01\n# User@Host: mmcite[mmcite] @ localhost []\n# Thread_id: 18712  Schema: mmcite  QC_hit: No\n# Query_time: 0.502068  Lock_time: 0.000030  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1\n# Rows_affected: 1\nuse mmcite;\nSET timestamp=1504512961;\nUPDATE `PAJKA` SET `id`='cotjo4mim2j7fp3ui2kit7gns6' WHERE id='pvueh0rm6l2meiguootdfqsan7';",
          "type" => "mysql_slow_log",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "beats_input_codec_plain_applied",
        [1] "_grokparsefailure"
    ]
}
```

Thank your very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea how, but it works.

```
grok {    
    match => { "message" => "#%{SPACE}Time:%{SPACE}%{NUMBER}%{SPACE}%{TIME}(.|\n)*%{HOSTNAME}\[%{HOSTNAME:mysql_host}\]%{SPACE}@%{SPACE}localhost \[\](.|\n)*#%{SPACE}Thread_id:%{SPACE}%{NUMBER}%{SPACE}Schema:%{SPACE}%{WORD}%{SPACE}%{WORD}:%{SPACE}%{WORD}(.|\n)*#%{SPACE}Query_time:%{SPACE}%{BASE16FLOAT:mysql_query_time}%{SPACE}Lock_time:%{SPACE}%{BASE16FLOAT:mysql_lock_time}%{SPACE}Rows_sent:%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:mysql_rows_sent}%{SPACE}Rows_examined:%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:mysql_rows_examined}(.|\n)*%{SPACE}Rows_affected:%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:mysql_rows_affected}(.|\n)*%{WORD}%{SPACE}%{WORD};(.|\n)*SET%{SPACE}timestamp=%{NUMBER:timestamp};(.|\n)%{GREEDYDATA:mysql_query}" }    
}
```

I've replaced the `\\n` before `%{GREEDYDATA:mysql_query}` by `(.|\n)`.